# Mark email as read with exchangelib

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, exchangelib

I am using Pythons `exchangelib` package. How can I mark an e-mail as read with exchangelib?

I have had a look at the [official GitHub exchangelib page](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/master/README.rst) for my query, but didn't find the answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To add to joe's comment, you must also 'save' the item for the flag to be permanent.

```
item.is_read = True
item.save()
```

Answer (score 6):

To add to HeroicOlive's comment, if you specifically want to save the `is_read` value only, try:

```
item.is_read = True
item.save(update_fields=['is_read'])
```

Answer (score 2):

item.is_read = True should do the trick where item is the message you want to mark read