# Python exchangelib - mark item as read

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I am trying to accomplish one task in my mailbox using Python's exchangelib module - how to move a certain email to a folder if it contains specific subject and has 'unread' status.

```
while True:
    print("Checking inbox...")
    for msg in acc.inbox.filter(subject="Kontrol fra EVT...", is_read=False):
        if "SOS" in msg.text_body:
            pass
        else:
            msg.is_read = True
            print("Moving to EVT folder...")
            msg.move(archive)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Everything appears to be working except for `msg.is_read = True` part. The message remains unread, despite being successfully moved to the required folder.

I believe I am missing something simple here. I tried googling and using official module's documentation but came up empty in this regard. Could find only one person with the same question as mine: [Mark email as read with exchangelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037322/mark-email-as-read-with-exchangelib)

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mark email as read with exchangelib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037322/mark-email-as-read-with-exchangelib)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the answer myself while digging through modules' files. Apparently you have to "save" the item after flagging it.
In the end my code should look like this:

```
while True:
    print("Checking inbox...")
    for msg in acc.inbox.filter(subject="Kontrol fra EVT...", is_read=False):
        if "SOS" in msg.text_body:
            pass
        else:
            msg.is_read = True
            msg.save()
            print("Moving to EVT folder...")
            msg.move(archive)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(5)
```