# Outlook COM object - Marking an Email as Read

Tags: python, outlook, win32com, office-automation, com-automation

Using w32 python library, I am taking an email and saving the attachment from Outlook.
I have seen several questions dealing with this topic with the most promising being here: [Marking an email as read python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216077/marking-an-email-as-read-python)

I have tried a few variations of the above answer but have been unable to get a working demo

```
# new outlook object
outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")

# get user namespace
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

# The default folder changes every time we boot up outlook
# This loop finds the correct inbox
for x in range(4):
    print(x)
    try:
        print(namespace.Folders.Item(x).name)
        if namespace.Folders.Item(x).name == 'John.Smith@foo.com':
            root_folder = namespace.Folders.Item(x)
            break
    except:
        pass

# Mark the item as read in the folder
for msg in root_folder.Folders['Inbox'].Folders('temp').Items:
    msg.is_read = True
    msg.save(updated_fields=['is_read'])
```

When I run the piece of code below I get the error

> AttributeError: Property '.is_read' can not be set.

Can anyone make any suggestions on how i might go about fixing this?

Comment: Figured it out. The answer is that `msg.is_read = True` should be converted to `msg.UnRead = False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> AttributeError: Property '.is_read' can not be set.

The Outlook object model provides the [UnRead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.unread) property instead.